# extra-index-url in WHEEL metadata

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, python-wheel

In a `requirements.txt` file, I can specify that certain packages should be found in a non-default index url via

```
--extra-index-url https://example.com/bar
mypackage >= 1.5
```

Now, if I create a wheel file which has `mypackage` as a dependency, how do I specify that in the wheel metadata? Currently, the [Requires-dist](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-dist-multiple-use) documentation shows how to specify the package name, version, and perhaps platform, but I cannot find the corresponding syntax for what index url should be searched.

Comment: I do not think it is possible.

Comment: I'm sure it is impossible. You cannot impose your URLs onto other people; for security and other reasons. There're 3 ways around that: 1) publish at PyPI; 2) document alternative URLs and wait while people come; 3) add `requirements.txt` to the distribution and document that people must run `pip install -r requirements.txt`